# Google Chrome cache Issue in Windows 7 over multiple systems

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit, taskbar, browser-cache

I am using Chrome with two systems both running on Windows 7 64-bit. I configured both instances of Chrome with my Google account, and everything worked perfectly.

Lately however I am having a hard time signing in to websites like Gmail, Google Docs, etc, especially Google websites. It is refreshing the sign in page and not letting me log in. On other sites like Facebook it is logging me out from time to time, and again I have to punch in my sign in details.

At first, I thought it was some kind of cache issue, so I cleared the cache from both my systems "from the beginning of time". However it is still not working, and it is irritating.

I don't want to lose my history or other details, so I only cleared the cache.

What should I do?